# Create var inside a for loop PLSQL ORACLE 11G

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have a function that puts a number in a var (`var1`). if `var1 = 3` then create **3** new variables and assign a value for later send that values in an out type. I don't know how can i do, my code is something like this where `"pos"` acts like an `INSTR()` that i know its each **13** chars. And `"newvar||var1"` is because i want my vars names be `newvar1`, `newvar2`, `newvar3`, etc.:

```sql
FOR n IN 1..var1
LOOP
  pos          NUMBER(4):= 0;
  newvar||var1 NUMBER(3);
  newvar||var1 := SUBSTR(TO_NUMBER(numberInsideString), 1, 1+pos);
  pos := pos+13;
END LOOP;
```

My question is, how a person who really know PLSQL would do that, im learning PLSQL please help. thank you.

Comment: Oracle 11g is ancient, time to upgrade. Instead of attempting to dynamically create variables, you should just use an array, start here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html

Comment: PL/SQL code gets compiled, it doesn't have an ability to dynamically generate itself. It looks like an XY problem, so please describe what do you want to achieve and why you cannot preallocate (`declare`) as much variables as you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to try to do suggests that you need a one dimensional array in order repeatedly to assign new values for each iteration within the loop. One of the types in **`OWA`** package such as **`vc_arr`**(*composed of `VARCHAR2` data type values*) is handy to define an array.

Coming to the code, you can start with moving the variables into the declaration section, and write such a simple code as a sample exercise

```sql
SET serveroutput ON

DECLARE
  pos                INT := 0;
  numberInsideString VARCHAR2(100):='as12df34sdg345apl8976gkh4f11öjhöh678u7jgvj';
  newvar             OWA.vc_arr;
BEGIN
  FOR n IN 1..3
  LOOP    
    newvar(n) := SUBSTR(numberInsideString, 1, 1+pos);
    pos := pos+5;
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(newvar(n));
  END LOOP;  
END;
/
a
as12df
as12df34sdg
```